# PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser working locally but not on a remote server

Tags: php, curl, simple-html-dom

I am making some web scraping app on my local (LAMPP - XAMPP for Linux) server and everything works ok. When I try to upload that project to my University account and run it from their server simple_html_dom behaves differently. I can only open pages with extension .html (eg. http://www.example.com/folder/index.html), but i can't open pages like (eg. http://www.example.com/folder/), even though i can open pages like that on my local server. I even tried using curl, but nothing happens. What could it be? Did they disable something on the server, or what?

Comment: It depends on the web server, some hosting services disabled DOM, thus there's no way executing it. On a side note, maybe post your code here, for diagnose.

Comment: It could be anything. You should contact the host admin or find a better one.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
require("simple_html_dom.php");

class PageExtractor {
    private $page;
    private $str;

    public function __construct($url) {
        $this->loadPage($url);
        if (!isset($this->page))
            echo "<strong>ERROR - Couldn't open the page";
    }
    public function loadPage($url) {
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $this->str = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        $this->page = new simple_html_dom();
        $this->page->load($this->str);
    }
    public function showPage() {
        echo $this->page;
    }
}
?>
```

So here is my class (here i am trying some workaround with curl, but it works without curl too, with just file_get_html($url).

```
<?php
require("PageExtractor.class.php");
$e = new PageExtractor("http://example.com/~folder/");
$e->showPage();
?>
```

When i do this on University server this code 'cuts off' the rest of my page so there are no closing tags. I've tried everything on both local and remote server, but locally its all good.

Comment: http://imgur.com/JHgpbcA what happens on a server when i put my php code inside this div, so i could display scraped info.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to create .htaccess file and place this code on top of it:

```
#Alternate default index page
DirectoryIndex index.html
```

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at Symphony [DOMCrawler Component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html). It's a very convenient tool for DOM crawling. It can be used as a standalone component.

Also, take a look at [Goutte PHP Web Scraper](https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/Goutte) library, which is based on Symphony DomCrawler and Guzzle HTTP library.

Comment: Why did it get downvoted? The question was about the right tool for DOM crawling and I proposed a good solution.